# If $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$, prove prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of measurable functions that converges in measure to $f$ on $[a,b]$.  If there is a Lebesgue integrable function $g$ on $[a,b]$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$, $\forall n\geq 1$, $\forall x\in [a,b]$, then prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

I'm stuck on the "converges in measure" part. I don't know what I'm allowed to assume from that. And where does that $g$ fit in?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: Can I assume/show $[a,b]$ is a measurable set? Then wouldn't this just be Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem?

edit2: Since $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of measurable functions and $f$ is a measurable function and if I can assume/show that $[a,b]$ is a measurable set, can I say $f_n\to f$ for $n\to\infty$?

Comment: $\mu(f_n)$ doesn't meant anything, usually.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Clarification please?

Comment: It's not me who needs to clarify something. Unless you define it, $\mu(f_n)$ doesn't mean anything in normal measure theory notation. Your use of this notation either means you have misunderstood some concept, or you need to tell us what it means according to the book you are using.

Comment: Convergence in measure implies there is a subsequence that converges to $f$ a.e.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah, my bad.  I was asking if that was correct notation for "converges in measure" or if it meant something else.

Comment: @zhw. Is there a more approachable way to states that?

Comment: @zhw It implies that a subsequence converges to $f$ a.e only when $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, right?

Comment: @DesperateFluffy maybe this definition here will help? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions)

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli Thanks! Can I assume this problem is talking global convergence?

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli I think that result works in any measure space. In the proof, you get trapped in a set of finite measure pretty quickly

Answer (score 1):

Idea: dominated convergence. It suffices to show that *every* convergent subsequence of $\int_a^b f_n(x)$ converges to $\int_a^b f(x)$

Suppose $\int_a^b f_{nk}(x)$ converges. Then since convergence in measure is assumed, {$f_{nk}$} contains a subsequence, {$f_{nkl}$} $\rightarrow $ f a.e. (Riesz Fischer)

By, the dominated Convergence Theorem, $\int_a^b f_{nkl}(x)$ $\rightarrow$$\int_a^b f(x)$

So, $\int_a^b f_{nk}(x)$ $\rightarrow$ $\int_a^b f(x)$

For *all* convergent $f_{nk}$ So,

$\int_a^b f_n(x)$ $\rightarrow$ $\int_a^b f(x)$

*The End*

Comment: Could you clarify line 2? So convergence of the measures imply the convergence of the integrals? I'm afraid I don't follow.

Comment: How? Is it a theorem or definition? Could you give more information, please?

Comment: @Jamie please delete your answer instead of vandalizing it.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: @timmbob OP's a dick/ looking for free answers and never contributes. I don't want it here anymore.

Comment: @JamieLannister Ok then just delete your answer but not only the text and OP can see your previous answer in the edit history while he will not be able to see a deleted answer